# Efeito (animação) no click em aplicativos Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Estou criando um aplicativo para o *Windows Phone 8.1*, usando a linguagem *C#*. Porém minha aplicação está com itens "estáticos" e ao clicar, ele não cria aquele efeito de entortar mostrando que selecionou algo. Alguém sabe como consigo inserir isso ?

Answer (score 1):

No código XAML existem as opções de ClickMode:

```
 <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="191,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClickMode="Hover"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClickMode="Press"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,161,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ClickMode="Release"/>
```

Você também pode fazer estas alterações por meio da propriedade do elemento

Comment: Obrigado Anderson. No meu caso seria o efeito do click em uma imagem por exemplo que será levado a uma outra página. De toda forma pode ajudar futuramente.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode utilizar o Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.

Baixe aqui: [The Windows Phone Toolkit](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/WindowsPhoneToolkit)

Exemplo de utilização:
[Nokia Developers](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tilt_Effect_for_Windows_Phone)